# Annotate missing values on a seaborn heatmap

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am plotting a heatmap in *python* with the `seaborn` library. The dataframe contains some missing values (`NaN`). I wish that the heatmap cells corresponding to these fields are white (by default) and also annotated with a string `NA`. However, if I see it correctly, annotation does not work with missing values. Is there any hack around it?

My code:

```
    sns.heatmap(
        df,
        ax=ax[0, 0],
        cbar=False,
        annot=annot_df,
        fmt="",
        annot_kws={"size": annot_size, "va": "center_baseline"},
        cmap="coolwarm",
        linewidth=0.5,
        linecolor="black",
        vmin=-max_value,
        vmax=max_value,
        xticklabels=True,
        yticklabels=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea is to draw another heatmap, with a transparent color and with only values where the original dataframe is `NaN`. To control the axis labels, the "real" heatmap should be drawn last. Note that the color for the `NaN` cells is the background color of the plot.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

data = np.where(np.random.rand(7, 10) < 0.2, np.nan, np.random.rand(7, 10) * 2 - 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
annot_df = df.applymap(lambda f: f'{f:.1f}')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(squeeze=False)
sns.heatmap(
    np.where(df.isna(), 0, np.nan),
    ax=ax[0, 0],
    cbar=False,
    annot=np.full_like(df, "NA", dtype=object),
    fmt="",
    annot_kws={"size": 10, "va": "center_baseline", "color": "black"},
    cmap=ListedColormap(['none']),
    linewidth=0)
sns.heatmap(
    df,
    ax=ax[0, 0],
    cbar=False,
    annot=annot_df,
    fmt="",
    annot_kws={"size": 10, "va": "center_baseline"},
    cmap="coolwarm",
    linewidth=0.5,
    linecolor="black",
    vmin=-1,
    vmax=1,
    xticklabels=True,
    yticklabels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To explicitly color the `'NA'` cells, e.g. `cmap=ListedColormap(['yellow'])` could be used.

Comment: Alternatively, or additionally, you can add hatching: `ax[0, 0].pcolor(np.where(df.isna(), 0, np.nan), hatch='xx', alpha=0)`

Comment: and what if I want only annotations to be 0? Is there a way to achieve that?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73977785/how-to-replace-blank-space-in-sns-heatmap-during-visualization-with-0-if-the-va?noredirect=1#comment130621091_73977785 . Thanks in advance