# How to replace blank space in sns heatmap during visualization with 0, if the value is NaN?

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, visualization, heatmap

after some data preprocessing I got a seaborn heatmap, but it has some white rows and column, I am already aware of bad values, but is there a way i can put in those blanks 0.0, directly while plotting the matrix,

The code that I have used is:

```
 from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
    corrmat0= cluster_0.corr()
    my_colors = ['dodgerblue', 'navajowhite', 'firebrick']; 
    my_cmap = ListedColormap(my_colors); bounds = [-2, 0.0, 0.99, 2]; 
    my_norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, ncolors=len(my_colors));
    plt.figure(figsize = (16,16)) 
   ax = sns.heatmap(corrmat0, annot=True, square=True, cmap=my_cmap, norm=my_norm)
```

The output I have is:

> [image: enter code here]

Comment: Have you tried to fill values with np.fillna("0.0")

Comment: Well, did you try something like `sns.heatmap(corrmat0.fillna(0), ...)`?